# Single Boot Ubunu 20.04 Instalation not working. Why?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Samsung Ativ Book 4 (Broken Dispaly)
Processor AMD E2-2000(smth like that)
1.7 Ghz

**BIOS**
Secure Boot - disabled
CSM and UEFI selected
FastBios Mode -disabled

***Partition setup #1***

- 512mb efi (I use this as boot)
- 100Gb ext4 /
- 4Gb swap
- 356 ntfs (this could be the problem but I have important data here)
- 35Gb unaccesible(i could delete the swap and use this but I prefer to have the swap)

I tried this variants also:

1) **CSM only** -> instalation sucessfull but result blinking thing like this _

(partitions

1)/ (boot)

2)swap

3)ntfs

4)/home

(I tried **Ctrl+Alt+F1** , holding **Shift** while booting and than pressing **E**, **Ctrl+Alt+F2** ,**Ctrl+Alt+F6** -> nothing worked)

2) **UEFI only** 
- same as partition #1 -> install not finished (grub error on the swap partition)

*I succeded once to install Ubuntu 20.04, I played in Gparted 
partition setup

1)efi

2)ext4 /

3)swap

4)unusable space1(free space)

5)ntfs

6)unusable space2 (free space)

(removed the swap partition, extended the / part to unusable space1 and rebooted )

silly me not wanting to unplug the broken display from the motherboard to be able to see the boot process on the secondary display I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 with many more configs but these 3 were the last ones.

Is there anyone who could help me, please ?
Or should I choose other distro . Or could it be the ubs port (when it worked I used other) ? Any ideeas ?

Comment: Is your disk using a `msdos` or `gpt` partition scheme? You can use `fdisk -l` or a possibly GUI tool like GParted to find it (you'll either see "DOS" for `msdos` or "GPT" for `gpt`). Because when booting through UEFI, the `gpt` partition scheme is preferred, and if your disk uses `msdos`, this may be what is causing your problems.

Comment: Yes, its dos, but how to do the install without deleting my data ?

Comment: Easiest course of action would be to backup your data > Change to gpt (will wipe all data) > Reinstall on the new gpt disk. I'm not sure if it's possible to convert to gpt wiithout wiping your data. But yes it is possible to install via UEFI on a MSDOS partition table but may or may not need manual grub installation - this answer to another question may be relavent https://stackoverflow.com/a/45648636/11902596